# How To get values of textfields from a UITableViewCell dynamic in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

**How to submit all `cell values` dynamic**

[image: Image Attached]

**Here is code** . I just hit the api and after that I append the values then I show all the `data`. **Right now the issue is how to text field all vaues get.**

```
func submitApi(){

    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading please wait........")
    let url = constatUrl + "url"
    print("catagory",url)


    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters:nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if let data = response.result.value{

                let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any]
                print("theloginAuthValue is ",json!)
                let responseStatus = json!["responseStatus"] as! Bool
                let responseText  = json!["responseText"] as! String


                if (responseStatus == true){

                    self.user_GLosary.removeAll()

                    self.productLabel.isHidden = false
                    self.quantyLabel.isHidden = false
                     self.quntySubmitButton.isHidden = false 

                    let responseData = json!["responseData"] as! [Any]
                    var index = 0
                    while index < responseData.count{

                        let responseArray = responseData[index] as! [String: Any]
                        let chainId = responseArray["id"] as? String
                        let chainValue = responseArray["value"] as? String

                        let folderAppend = FolderGlosaryDetails()
                       folderAppend.glosaryId = chainId
                       folderAppend.glosaryName = chainValue
                       self.user_GLosary.append(folderAppend)

                        index += 1
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.openingStockTableView.reloadData()
                    } 
                }    
                else if (responseStatus == false){

                    self.displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: responseText)
                } 
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            print("faliure",response.result.error!)
            self.displayAlertMessage(messageToDisplay: "Something Wrong Please try again")
            break

        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user_GLosary.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"OpeningStockCell",for: indexPath) as! OpeningStockCell

    cell.stockLabel.text = user_GLosary[indexPath.row].glosaryName
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What you are expecting.

Comment: I expected all text field value will be store in empty array

Comment: `cell.yourTextField.tag = indexPath.raw`
`cell.yourTextField.delegate = self` that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not so clear but i think you want to store your textfield value into some array from tableviewCell, so bellow code may help you.

First, define array for store value into. i,m taking string array here you can take as per your need.

```
var arrayValue:Array<String>!
```

Then store your textfield value from cell into array.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"OpeningStockCell",for: indexPath) as! OpeningStockCell

    cell.stockLabel.text = user_GLosary[indexPath.row].glosaryName

    // here you can see how you can get value from textfield
    arrayValue.append(cell.yourTextField.text!)
    return cell


}
```

Comment: not working properly. I Want to store all cell value in  an array